# Dynamic SQL using 'where current of'

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a pretty generic/dynamic procedure where I pass in the table name as a parameter and execute queries dynamically using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. I need to loop through a cursor and update each record. Is there a way to not have to hard code my table name??

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
    open cur for v_sql;
    loop
        fetch cur into v_recid;
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update '||p_table||q'[ set status = 'I' where current of cur]'; 
    end loop;
    close cur;
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `ROWID` as key for the update?

Comment: What is the error you're having? If you're using "current of", your query associated to the cursor needs to have the "for update" clause.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a set oriented language.  Your solution is row at a time or "slow at a time".  I'd recommend spending your time to figure a way do not loop and do the update in a single statement.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I realized soon after posting the question and decided to go with this approach. But was still curious if it could be done. I didn't realize 'where current of' is that slow.